# Hide related list depending on a picklist

Tags: apex, community

RESPECT POST
I have created 4 look ups  in the opportunity object that is related to my custom object roles.
I created 4 lookups so in the custom object role, I have 4 related list.
This is my question, how can I hide the 3 other related list and show only the related list which is the role of the person. 
Thanks in advance StackExperts. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create 4 record types, and 4 page layouts(each associated with different layouts, and each containing required related lists)

Based on the data in the record, you have to change the record type in the trigger (Since workflow action would not update record type)